# True/False function if a sum exists

Tags: c++, loops, boolean

I want to have a program that returns true when there exist such positive integer numbers `a` and `b` such that `a*a+b*b=n*n`.

My code is:

```
 bool c(int n){
    int b=1;
    int a=1;
    for (a=1; a<=n; a++) {
        for (b=a; b<=n; b++) {
            if (a*a + b*b == n*n) {
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

}
```

However this code does not return what i want it to. What can i do to fix that?

Please everybody before you down vote please explain what could be improved in this question. I have noticed that sometimes people have a tendency to down vote questions without any explanation.

Comment: What if the condition is never true? What do you return then?

Comment: Step #1 - make the function return in all code paths. Step #2 - use debugger. Also, where is `c` defined?

Comment: Step #2 - use your variable `n`.

Comment: I am not certain whether i know what to return in all code paths.

Comment: a,b positive integers n by implication needs to be positive integer as well

Comment: If you don't return `true`, then what else would you return that is a `bool`? And if the condition is never true, what will happen to the loops?

Comment: Did your compiler warn you ?`

Comment: @Mroweczka n*n is positive also for negative n

Comment: @tobi303 yes obviously, i think it doest not matter then.

Comment: @MichaelWalz "main.cpp|233|error: expected primary-expression before ';' token|"

Comment: @Mroweczka sorry your comment does not contain enough information. What did you do ? What happended ? We don't know the content of  main.cpp etc.

Comment: You asked about any compiler errors. This is the only error i have main.cpp is only the function and obviously it is used there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program doesn't compile. You probably intended to write this:

```
bool c(int n) {
  int b = 1;
  int a = 1;
  for (a = 1; a <= n; a++) {
    for (b = a; b <= n; b++) {
      if (a*a + b*b == n*n)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

which compiles, but which is wrong.

But you probably want this:

```
bool myfunction(int n) {
  int b = 1;
  int a = 1;
  for (a = 1; a <= n; a++) {
    for (b = a; b <= n; b++) {
      if (a*a + b*b == n*n)
        return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

int main() {
  if (myfunction(5)) {
    printf("myfunction(5) returned true\n");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bool c(int n){
int b=1;
int a=1;
for (a=1; a<=n; a++) {
    for (b=a; b<=n; b++) {
        if (a*a + b*b == n*n) {
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
}
```

The code you have written will check for a=1 and b=1 and that evaluates to 1 + 1 equals to 2.

So,all that your code does is compare 2 to n.

The `return false` statement should be outside both the for loops.
This means that for all combination of a and b there exists no pair (a,b) such that a*a + b*b = n*n.